# Replacing underscores in JSON using JQ

Tags: json, regex, key, jq, camelcasing

I'm working with the [woocommerce](http://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/) API to retrieve and store information. Currently our setup is designed to use camel case instead of underscores. I'm using `jq` to process our information, but I'm curious how I can use the `sub(regex, tostring)` function to replace the underscores in my JSON with camelCase?

Here's an example of the code

```
"line_items": [
    {
     "id": xxxx,
     "name": "xxxx",
     "sku": "xxxx",
     "product_id": xxxx,
    }
```

For example, according to another answer on SO that I found, this works: `curl https://www.testsite.com/wp-json/wc/v1/orders -u user:pass | jq '.[] | with_entries( if .key | contains("_") then .key |= sub("_";"") else . end)'` and remove the underscores.

The result is:

```
"lineitems": [
    {
     "id": xxxx,
     "name": "xxxx",
     "sku": "xxxx",
     "productid": xxxx,
    }
```

However, when I try `curl https://www.testsite.com/wp-json/wc/v1/orders -u user:pass | jq '.[] | with_entries( if .key | contains("_") then .key |= sub("(\\_)([a-z])";"$2\u") else . end)'` I don't get the results I would expect.

The expected results would be:

```
"lineItems": [
    {
     "id": xxxx,
     "name": "xxxx",
     "sku": "xxxx",
     "productId": xxxx,
    }
```

I don't have a lot of experience using `jq` so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Is there a better solution to this problem?

Answer (score 15):

Here's a jq function that will convert "a_bcd_ef" to "aBcdEf", which seems to be what you want:

```
def camel:
  gsub( "_(?<a>[a-z])"; .a|ascii_upcase);
```

Example usage:

```
"a_bcd_ef" | camel
```

If you want a simple one-liner to process JSON strings from STDIN:

```
$ jq 'gsub( "_(?<a>[a-z])"; .a|ascii_upcase)'
```

If you only want the first occurrence of "_[a-z]" converted, then of course you'd use `sub`. And so on.

To apply this function to ALL keys in an object, you could write:

```
with_entries( .key |= camel )
```

To change ALL keys in ALL objects within a JSON entity, you could use `walk/1`:

```
walk(if type == "object" then with_entries(.key |= camel) else . end)
```

If your jq does not have `walk/1` then you can simply include its definition (easily found by googling), either before it is invoked, or perhaps in your ~/.jq file.

Answer (score 6):

Although not as concise as the gsub solution of @peak, this one is easier on the eye and easier for beginners to understand IMHO.

You can put this into a script called 'snake_to_camel.jq' and `chmod +x snake_to_camel.jq`

```js
#!/usr/bin/env jq -f
def head:
  .[0:1];

def tail:
  .[1:];

def capitalize:
  (head | ascii_upcase) + tail;

def snake_to_camel:
  split("_") |
  head + (tail | map(capitalize)) |
  join("");

def map_keys(mapper):
  walk(if type == "object" then with_entries(.key |= mapper) else . end);

map_keys(snake_to_camel)
```

Example usage:

```sh
curl https://example.com/input.json | ./snake_to_camel.jq
```

Some of the jq features I've used here:

- [slices](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Array/StringSlice:.%5B10:15%5D) for head and tail
- [ascii_upcase](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#ascii_downcase,ascii_upcase)
- [addition](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Addition:+) for array concatenation
- [split](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#split(str)) and [join](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#join(str))
- [walk](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#walk(f))
- [with_entries](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#to_entries,from_entries,with_entries)