# Rename property of an object inside array

Tags: jq

This is my input JSON

```
{
"uuid":123,
"description": [
    {
        "car_name":"Toyota",
        "saleDate":"23 May 2017"
    }
  ]
}
```

Expected output:

```
{
"uuid":123,
"description": [
    {
        "name":"Toyota",
        "saleDate":"23 May 2017"
    }
  ]
}
```

Rule : .description[]|={name:.car_name,saleDate}

I am able to achieve the desired result with this rule. However, is there a way I can rename the 'car_name' property to 'name' and also not mention all the other properties ( in this case, 'saleDate') in the rule. I might end up having 50+ properties inside the object and I do not want to mention all of them in the rule.

There can be more than one object in the array.

Answer (score 3):

To preserve the order of keys while being sure only to change the specific key name:

```
jq '.description[] |= with_entries(if .key == "car_name" then .key = "name" else . end)'
```

Answer (score 1):

I just learned about += from an answer to another question. It works here too.

```
jq '.description[] |= (select(has("car_name")) += {"name":.car_name} | del(.car_name))'
```

The select function selects the objects that meet the condition. Then we add to, and delete from, those objects.

Comment: Yea. However, I found one issue with this way of renaming the fields. It ends up placing the new field in a different position than before. That's because we are creating a new field and deleting the old one. I wish there was a way to actually rename the field, ensuring my output json looks similar to the input in terms of order of the properties.

Comment: I don't know if jq can do that. It might; I genuinely don't know. I suppose you could do something like sed 's/"car_name"/"name"/g'

Comment: See the answer above for a jq solution.

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you want?

```
 jq '.description[]
     |= . +
       if has("car_name") then {"name":.car_name}
       else null end
     | del(.description[].car_name)'
```

The if-then block adds the object {name:.car_name} to any object in the description array that has a key with the name "car_name" and adds nothing (null) to any object in the array that does not have a key with that name.

The del function deletes key-value pairs at the path expression .description[].car_name

Comment: Yes it did! Thank you. Seems so simple now.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work while preserving the order.

```
jq '.description[] |= with_entries( .key |= gsub("car_name"; "name") )'
```

The [jq manual](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.5/) explains what with_entries does.

Credit goes to an [answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40367791/7839189) by peak.

Comment: Warning: this could change more than just the key named "car_name".

Answer (score 0):

```
jq '.description[] |= with_entries(if .key == "car_name" then .key = "name" else . end)'
```