# How to convert json property names from snake to camel case

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I have a json document like so... and I'm trying to convert the property names (not values) from snake case to camel.

ex  -
message_type_id to messageTypeId
and _id to id
and point_altitude to pointAltitude

```
{
  "@version": "1",
  "point_altitude": 530,
  "_id": "3325",
  "header": {
    "raw_message": "",
    "message_type_id": "ping_event"
   }

}
```

I've tried find `((\w)[_]{1,1}([a-z]{1,1}))` and replace `$1\U$2`

but that also changes the values as well. I've also tried using positive lookaheads by adding `.+?(?=\:)` to the end of the find but that stops finding any second underscores in the property names.

https://regex101.com/r/jK5mP3/14

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Doing this with a single regex replace is possible but probably not the best choice. Try

```
(?<=[\w])(?:_([a-z]))([^_"]*+)(?!"\s)|"_([a-z]+)"
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/VMtzhe/2)

I would rather suggest parsing the JSON and simply iterate of the property names.   Depending on your environment, you could use code or a library like [camelize](https://github.com/substack/camelize) or a command-line tool like [jd](https://github.com/josephburnett/jd) (e.g. this [jd answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40367791/8291949) deals with a similar problem).